# I can't solve "invalid nib registered for identifier (BNRItemCell)"

Tags: ios, uitableview

Going through the Big Nerd Ranch iOS book, and I'm on day 2 of trying to solve this and I'm going crazy - can anyone help?

I get the following error message:

> 2014-06-20 11:37:18.764 Homepwner[10388:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (BNRItemCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'

I've hooked up the BNRItemCell.xib to the corresponding class. Things fail after line 57 where the breakpoint is:

[image: fluffy kitten]

=======================================================

[image: tour de france]

=======================================================

[image: cycling]

I know that it's gonna be something so basic that I'll kick myself.

Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Could you send me the project ?

Comment: what if i want to use single xib for multiple cell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Observing the TreeView on the left of the IB you have a UIView ( second top level element! ) below the UITableViewCell. Delete it and you should be fine!

Comment: Aha! Yes there was something: http://i.imgur.com/XWL21JM.png Thank you!! Now I know what that TreeView does :)

Comment: @MABVT If i not want to delete that view because i need to draw it in actual cell; How can i achieve this behaviour? Actually i have two subviews and need to show one on some run time logic.

Comment: @msmq you then have to load the nib "by hand" and traverse all items you have in the file and filter the required ones. You do this by `NSArray *uiItems = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:<name> owner:<owner> options:<options>];`. The array then contains all top level items as seen in the IB-Tree. See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed:owner:options: and this http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/ for its way to be used!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. It turns out I had added another view by mistake on the .xib file