# Can't use custom object in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xib

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (SSSomeCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

But if i want use there my own custom `Object`,like object with drawn images to bind them into cell's image view directly? Is there any workaround for this?

There is no additional views in xib, only my specific object, that i need. That object causes this issue, but it's not about why i got this error. I ask about help to get workaround to use this object via xib.

[image]

Comment: Do you have other views in this xib file except `SSSomeCell`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't solve "invalid nib registered for identifier (BNRItemCell)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328723/i-cant-solve-invalid-nib-registered-for-identifier-bnritemcell)

Comment: No, there is nothing about others views in this xib. You can see it at image that i added. It's not about issue itself. It's about how to workaround it, when i NEED the additional data object in xib. I think i described it well. Please, read it mindfully. Thanks :)

Comment: Is "SSSomeCell" a subclass of UITableViewCell or something else?

Comment: It is a subclass of UITableViewCell.